# How to use POSIX regexp in Spring Data Specification

Tags: java, regex, postgresql, spring-data, posix

This is a Book that has "words" in the manner of "word1;word2;word3":

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "books")
public class Book {
    ... 

    @Column(name ="words")
    private String words;
}
```

I need to find Books containing the specified word. I have:

```
@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Book> {}

@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class BookServiceImpl implements BookService {

    private BookRepository bookRepository;

    @Override
    public List<Book> getAllBooksByWord(String word) {
        return bookRepository.findAll(BookSpecification.hasWord(word));
    }
}

public class BookSpecification {

    public final String delimiter = ";";

    public static Specification<Book> hasWord(String word) {
        return (root, query, cb) -> 
            cb.like(
                root.get("words"), 
                MessageFormat.format("^{0}{1}|^{0}$|.*{1}{0}{1}.*|{1}{0}$", word, delimiter)
            );
    }
}
```

The problem is that `cb.like()` does not work with POSIX regular expressions that I can use in [postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP:%7E:text=9.7.3.-,POSIX%20Regular%20Expressions,-Table%C2%A09.16%20lists). Using the `cb.like()` method, I get a query `SELECT ... FROM books WHERE words LIKE '^w;|^w$|.*;w;.*|;w$'` that doesn't understand POSIX regular expressions and the WHERE clause doesn't work.

Is there a way to force `cb.like()` to create a query with a "~" operator that understands POSIX, instead of LIKE: `SELECT ... FROM books WHERE words ~ '^w;|^w$|.*;w;.*|;w$'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, however you need to create a function in PostgreSQL:

```sql
create or replace function regexp_match(v_text in varchar, v_regexp in varchar) returns boolean
    language plpgsql strict immutable
as
$$
begin
  return v_text ~ v_regexp;
end
$$;
```

Criteria:

```java
cb.equal(
   cb.function(
      "regexp_match",
      Boolean.class,
      root.get("words"),
      MessageFormat.format("^{0}{1}|^{0}$|.*{1}{0}{1}.*|{1}{0}$", word, delimiter)
   ),
   cb.literal(true)
)
```

Though, I'm not sure whether HBN allows to bind booleans

Comment: There is already a function equivalent to `~`, it is spelled `textregexeq`.  It might be better to use that than to make a new one.

Comment: Actually signature of `cb.function()` is `function(String name, Class<T> type, Expression<?>... args)`, so I have to use
`cb.function(... , cb.literal(MessageFormat.format(...))`